# MVC Model in the View not Updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a very basic MVC project that does maths operations (+ - / *) of 2 numbers

for some reasons my view is not updating after postback

**here is my controller**

```
namespace MathsAppMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        MathsServiceClient loClient = new MathsServiceClient();
        Int32 loNum1 = 0;
        Int32 loNum2 = 0;
        //Int32 result = 0;
        String locOperation = "Add";

        public ActionResult Index()
        {                                
            var model = new MathsModel
            {
                Number1 = loNum1,
                Number2 = loNum2,
                //Result = result,
                MathsOperation = locOperation
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MathsOperation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MathsOperation(MathsModel mathsModel)
        {

            loNum1 = mathsModel.Number1;
            loNum2 = mathsModel.Number2;
            locOperation = mathsModel.MathsOperation;

            if (locOperation == "Add")
            {
                mathsModel.Result = loClient.add(loNum1, loNum2);
            }
            else if (locOperation == "Subtract")
            {
                mathsModel.Result = loClient.subtract(loNum1, loNum2);
            }
            else if (locOperation == "Multiple")
            {
                mathsModel.Result = loClient.multiple(loNum1, loNum2);
            }
            else
            if (locOperation == "Divide")
            {
                mathsModel.Result = loClient.divide(loNum1, loNum2);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", mathsModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

HERE IS VIEW

```
@model MathsAppMVC.Models.MathsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MathsOperation", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    <fieldset>            
            <legend>Maths:</legend>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.MathsOperation)</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.MathsOperation, new SelectList(
                  new List<Object>
                  { 
                       new { value = "Add" , text = "Add"  },
                       new { value = "Subtract" , text = "Subtract" },
                       new { value = "Multiple" , text = "Multiple"},
                       new { value = "Divide" , text = "Divide"}
                  },
                  "value",
                  "text",
                   0))
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Number1)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.Number1)</div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Number2)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.Number2)</div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Result)</div>
            <div>@Html.DisplayTextFor(u=>u.Result)</div>    

            <input type="submit" value ="Calculate" />
            <input type="reset" value ="Clear" />

        </fieldset>

}
```

In the view after postback for what ever reason the Result is always 0.

Some one please help?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to post this as an answer, but that's all I can do with my amount of reputation. I literally copied and pasted your code into a new MVC project and it works fine. Can you post your MathsServiceClient code?